# Proving cardinality given surjection from A to B and B to A

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Suppose f:A→B and g:B→A are both surjective, does this imply that there is a bijection between A and B.

I was told that the statement above is true only with Axiom of Choice. Can someone provide an example of why that is the case?

Comment: With the Axiom of Choice you can pick right inverses for both $f$ and $g$, and then use regular Cantor-Bernstein on those inverses. However, this result implies the Axiom of Countable Choice, so it cannot be proven in ZF. See [this math.overflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38771/dual-schroeder-bernstein-theorem)

Comment: See also these previous threads here: [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1387151/to-prove-two-sets-are-isomorphic-is-it-sufficient-to-find-2-injections-or-2-surj), [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192460/there-exists-an-injection-from-x-to-y-if-and-only-if-there-exists-a-surjecti), and [three](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659964/when-do-surjections-split-in-zf-two-surjections-imply-bijection)